# EIGRP to BGP to EIGRP

Tags: routing, vpn, bgp, eigrp, redistribution

I would like to ask if it is possible to implement eigrp routing sent through bgp?
[image]

I wanted to route from PC-1 to PC-2 using EIGRP. The connection between all of the three routers are through BGP protocol. PC-3 should not receive any routing to PC-1 and PC-2. T

The problem is now I can ping from PC-1 to RTR-3, however there is no route to PC-2. All of the redistribution route I found from internet is only from EIGRP to BGP. So is it possible from EIGRP to BGP to EIGRP back?

RTR-1

```
router bgp 10000
network 1.1.1.0 mask 255.255.255.252
neighbor 1.1.1.1 remote-as 10001

router eigrp 100
network 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
redistribute bgp 10000
```

RTR-2

```
router bgp 10001
network 1.1.1.0 mask 255.255.255.252
network 2.2.2.0 mask 255.255.255.252
network 192.168.3.0 mask 255.255.255.0
neighbor 1.1.1.2 remote-as 10000
neighbor 2.2.2.2 remote-as 10000
```

RTR-3

```
router bgp 10000
network 2.2.2.0 mask 255.255.255.252
neighbor 2.2.2.1 remote-as 10001

router eigrp 100
network 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255
redistribute bgp 10000
```

Edit:

Is it feasible if I were also to use DMVPN/Site to Site tunnel network and advertise to IGP?

Comment: Why do you have EIGRP on RTR-1 and RTR-3? There are no EIGRP neighbors for either of those routers, so the EIGRP configurations are actually doing nothing. Simply putting in network statements into BGP on those two routers will make the routing work.

Comment: Is it feasible if I were also to use DMVPN tunnel network and advertise to IGP?

Comment: I just do not see the point of the EIGRP configuration. Why burden your router with unnecessary protocols? Just remove the EIGRP configurations and add the networks to the BGP configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding a fundamental concept of routing protocols.  ***Routing protocols do not route packets***.  They exchange routing information (reachability) with other routers.  You run a routing protocol on two or more routers so they can exchange routing information.  If you only have one router, you don't need a rotuing protocol, because there is no one for that router to exchange information with.

So in your network, routers 1,2, and 3 exchange information via the BGP protocol -- they learn each other's networks.  Router 1 and 3 do not talk directly with each other, so there is no point in running EIGRP on them -- it does absolutely nothing except waste CPU cycles.

On Router 1 and 2, add a network statement under the BGP configuration for the connected network:

```
network 192.168.x.0 mask 255.255.255.0
```

If you want Routers 1 and 3 to exchange information directly without getting Router 2 involved (for example, if router 2 was an ISP), then you can configure a tunnel between them (GRE, DMVPN, etc) so they can talk directly with each other as if Router 2 doesn't exist.